# Adding a link to an image path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add an image for every asset. In my code below I try pulling it, but no image appears on the screen. My images are stored in the same folder as `data.js` and `App.js`.

I think this is where the error is but not 100% sure: `<img src={asset.path} alt="pic"/>`

Any idea how I can get the images to appear?

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {collections} from "./data.js"
import {assets} from "./data.js"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
           collectionsarr: collections,
           assetsarr: assets,
           clickedassets: []
        }
    }

    handleAssetsClick(id){
      const clickedassetsdata = this.state.assetsarr.filter(asset => asset.collectionId === id)
      this.setState({
        clickedassets: clickedassetsdata
      })
    }
  
  render(){
  return (
          <div className="App">
            <h1>Sitecore coding challenge</h1>
            
            <div className="left">
              {this.state.collectionsarr.map(element => 
                <div key={element.id}>
                  <p onClick={()=>this.handleAssetsClick(element.id)}>{element.name}</p>
                  <p>thumbnail master asset</p>
                  <br></br>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>

            <div className="right">
                {this.state.clickedassets.map(asset => 
                  <div key={asset.id}>
                    <img src={asset.path} alt="pic"/>
                    <p>{asset.name}</p>
                    <p>{asset.id}</p>
                  </div>
                )}
            </div>
          </div>
        )
  }
}

export default App
```

**data.js**

```
const assets = [
    {
        id: 11,
        name: "Homer Simpson",
        path: "Homer.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        name: "Lisa Simpson",
        path: "Lisa.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        name: "Bart Simpson",
        path: "Bart.jpg",
        collectionId: 1,
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use relative path:

```
src={`/relativeToYourImage/${asset.path}`}
```

or you can do like that:

```
src={require(asset.path)}
```

Another variant to define a path like that:

```
const assets = [
    {
        id: 11,
        name: "Homer Simpson",
        path: require("./Homer.jpg"), // or require("/Homer.jpg"),
        collectionId: 1,
    }
]

src={asset.path}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that earlier, but it's still not working...there must be another reason

Comment: What do you mean with relative to your image?The images are in the same folder as data.js and App.js. Also: I tried the second approach and this give me this error: Error: Cannot find module 'Homer.jpg' => which is the the first path

Comment: try to change your assets array: `path: require("./Homer.jpg")` or  `path: require("/Homer.jpg")`. Depends of your project structure.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say here with: path: require("./Homer.jpg") or path: require("/Homer.jpg")

Comment: Anyone that could have a look?